C# WPF Programmatically adding a button to StackPanel causes entire program to resize
I am trying to add a button programmatically to a StackPanel. When I do so, the entire program window resizes to an absurdly small window, but resizing back up to 1080p looks fine. I am using a Viewbox to contain all of the elements.
https://youtu.be/8EX61n0zfhI Here's a video demonstration of the issue.
private Button SetUpButton(string name, BitmapImage image, string tooltip)
{
    Button button = new Button()
    {
        Name = Utility.ReplaceWhitespace(name, "") + "Button",
        Content = new Image { Source = image },
        ToolTip = tooltip,
        FontSize = 16,
        HorizontalContentAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Center,
        HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Center,
        VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Center,
        Margin = new Thickness(7),
        Width = Height = 100
    };
    return button;

}

private void AddButton() {

    UpgradePanel.Children.Add(SetUpButton("buttonex", image, "test"));
}

<Grid   Height="172" Margin="20,725,1052,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Background="LightGray">
    <Label Content="Upgrades" HorizontalAlignment="Left" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center"  Margin="10,5,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="651" FontSize="30"/>
    <StackPanel Name="UpgradePanel" Margin="10,60,10,10" Orientation="Horizontal"/>



</Grid>

Here's a code demonstration of what I'm trying to do as well as the XAML for the StackPanel. Changing the width and height of the button doesn't change the fact that the window is resized.

Read up on the WPF Grid.  By default, rows and columns take up the least amount of space necessary to accommodate the largest content within any cell contained in a given row or column.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.grid?view=windowsdesktop-8.0
